# If $I$ and $J$ are distinct maximal ideals of $R$, any module homomorphism $R/I\to R/J$ is zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am not sure how to deal with the following problem:

$I$ and $J$ are distinct maximal ideals in a commutative ring $R$ and if $\phi$ is a  modules homomorphism from $R$-module $R/I$ to $R$-module $R/J$, then it must be trivial.

I've just started to learn Modules Theory.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $I$ and $J$ are maximal, the modules $R/I$ and $R/J$ are simple. A module $M$ is simple when its only submodules are $\{0\}$ and $M$; simplicity of $R/I$ is exactly the same as maximality of $I$, by the homomorphism theorems.

If $f\colon R/I\to R/J$, then you have just two possibilities:

1. $\ker f=\{0\}$; in this case $f$ must be an isomorphism (prove it);
2. $\ker f=\{R/I\}$; in this case $f$ is the trivial homomorphism.

You have to exclude case 1; how? If $x\in R$, then the annihilator of $x+I\in R/I$ contains $I$ (prove it). If $f\colon M\to N$ is an isomorphism and $x\in M$, then the annihilator of $x$ is the same as the annihilator of $f(x)$.

Recall that the annihilator of $x\in M$ is $\{r\in R:rx=0\}$ (which is an ideal of $R$).

Comment: Maximal ideals are prime, so annihilator of $x$ in $R/I$ is exactly $I$, whilst annihilator of $f(x)$ in $R/J$ is $J$. If $f$ is an isomorphism, then $I=J$ which is a contradiction.

Am I right?

Comment: @DeltaDelta The annihilator of $x\ne0$ in $R/I$ is $I$ (by maximality). The argument is correct by just adding the $\ne0$ bit, since isomorphisms send nonzero elements to nonzero elements.

Comment: I have one more question. Supposing that I don't know about $I$ and $J$ they are maximal, but I do know that there exists isomorphism $f:R/I \rightarrow R/J$. Can I prove that $I=J$?

In that situation I can prove that $I\subset Ann_{R}(R/I)$ and $J\subset Ann_{R}(R/J)$ and I know that $Ann_{R}(R/I)=Ann_{R}(R/J)$ and that $f(I)=J$. Is it enough to say $I=J$?

Comment: @DeltaDelta The annihilator of $1+I$ is $I$; the annihilator of any element in $R/J$ contains $J$; thus $I\supseteq J$, considering $f(1+I)$. The converse inclusion follows in the same way using $f^{-1}$.